# Convergence Rate of Smoothing Splines

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, convergence-divergence, asymptotics, spline

Consider the regression model with data $(Y_i, x_i)_{i=1}^{n}$ (i.e. real-valued target and univariate predictor $x_i$)
$$
Y_i = f(x_i) + \epsilon
$$
with $\epsilon$ iid, $E(\epsilon) = 0$ and $\operatorname{Var}(\epsilon) = \sigma^2$.

Suppose the true underlying function $f$ is three-times differentiable and is taken from an appropriate Sobolev-space, i.e.
$ W_2^{v} = \{f:f \ (v-1)-\text{times continuously differentiable and} \int_a^b[f^{(v)}(x)]^2 < \infty \}$ with $v=3$.

Consider a smoothing spline solving the penalized least-squares problem with smoothing parameter $\lambda \geq 0$
$$
g_r(\lambda) = \operatorname{argmin}_{f \in W_2^{r}}1/n \sum_i \left[Y_i - f(x_i)\right]^2 + \lambda \int \left[f^{(r)}(x)\right]^2dx.
$$

I am interested in the asymptotic behaviour $(n \to \infty)$ (where $n$ is the sample size) of a cubic smoothing spline and $v > r = 2$. In particular, at which mean-squared error rate does the cubic smoothing spline converge (since it is only twice differentiable and belongs to Sobolev space with $r=2$?)?

To make this more precise, due to Speckman (1985) I know that every linear smoother has a (minimax) convergence rate of $O(n^{-2v/(2v+1)})$. Does the cubic smoothing spline converge at the rate $O(n^{-6/7})$ (although it is chosen of order $r$) or at the (lower) rate $O(n^{-4/5})$?

The question is basically: If I choose the order of the smoothing spline too low does the smoothing spline converge with the optimal rate of (in this example) $O(n^{-6/7})$ or lower.

Comment: My numerical analysis teacher used to say that these types of problems are difficult.  I would give it a shot if I understood  your question, but I don't.  What are you trying to minimize?  Is $\lambda$ just a constant greater than zero?  What does $[Y_i - f(x_i)]^2$ mean?  Does it mean to just square the difference $(Y_i - f(x_i))^2$?  Is your spline piecewise cubic where the third derivative is discontinuous only at the $x_i$?  Is $Y_i$ the value of the spline function at $x_i$?

Comment: I made the question more precise. Hopefully, it is clear now ....